# SKAction follow path with orient and rotate at the same time

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skaction

I am using the following code to make an object follow a circlular path and maintain its orientation:

```
SKAction.follow(self.path!, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 100.0)
```

It looks good when it is the only object traveling the circle, but when I add other physics bodies to the scene and get the other objects to bump into the first one, I want it to continue to follow the path around the circle with the newly bumped orientation and bumped offset position. 
Right now the object gets bumped by the other objects, but then immediately corrects the orientation again to the original state.

Any idea how can I achieve the look that I am going for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the object collides with another object, why not simply delete the current ‘follow’ action and start a new one with orientToPath as false?

Answer (score 0):

When the object collides with another object, in `didBegin(contact:)` delete the current ‘follow’ action and create a new one with `orientToPath` as false.

Comment: I believe the path would also have to be rebuilt from the location you are at

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts and like the idea of using the collision to adjust what is going on.